# How would I parse a text file into a 3D array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a text file with a dimension of 82355. I want to define this as density(82355) and parse this into a three-dimensional array called `rho(5,91,181)`, where

- 5 is for the number of days,
- 91 is for the number of latitudes,
- 181 is for the number of longitudes.

This is an example of the text file with the first 11 values. There are 5 days with latitudes from -90 to 90 in two-degree steps. For each latitude, there will be 180 rows, corresponding to longitudes from 0 to 360 in two-degree steps.

```
       Latitude  Longitude           rho
0         -90.0        0.0  3.396760e-12
1         -90.0        2.0  3.397140e-12
2         -90.0        4.0  3.397510e-12
3         -90.0        6.0  3.397870e-12
4         -90.0        8.0  3.398470e-12
5         -90.0       10.0  3.399060e-12
6         -90.0       12.0  3.399810e-12
7         -90.0       14.0  3.400560e-12
8         -90.0       16.0  3.401440e-12
9         -90.0       18.0  3.402310e-12
10        -90.0       20.0  3.403200e-12
```

I'm confused how to start and parse this text file with dimension 82355 into a 3D array called rho(5,91,181) in Python. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: rho(5,91,181) is not a valid Python identifier, rho_5_91_181 would be. What would be the tree axis of your array ? (days, latitude, longitude) and rho being the value ? If yes, it seems hard to achieve as array indices need to be positive integers. Could a nested dictionary fit your problem ? you would be able to get the value for any existing day longitude latitude triplet (rho_5_91_181[day][longitude][latitude]). Even better if you use a defaultdict you could return an invalid value in case the triplet does not exit. For parsing, you can use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: It seems like your data is missing the day column. However, you could try representing it as a sparse 3D array (the underlying data will still be stored in a table, but you would be able to call find the values using rho[day, latitude, longitude]).

Comment: What is the rule that tells you where one day's data stops and the next starts? How do you want a "3-dimensional array" to be represented in your program? The built-in `list` type is not an array, and a list of lists is definitely not the same as a multidimensional array.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel There are five separate files that I put together earlier in my code, so they are now in one large text file. Each new day starts with -90.0 latitude and 0.0 longitude.

Answer (score 1):

The file itself is quite easy to parse as it seems to be in standard tsv format. You only need to specify how the day is calculated, then just go over each row and put the rho value into the right place of array:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_data_file', sep=r'[ \t]+')
rho = np.zeros((5, 9, 181))
for i, e in df.iterrows():
    day = calc_day_from(i, e)
    lat = int((e['Latitude'] + 90) / 2)
    long = int(e['Longitude'] / 2)
    rho[day, lat, long] = e['rho']
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! What does ``` sep=r'[ \t]+' mean when reading the csv. I have the file called density.txt but there are other text files in the same folder too. Would that be an issue? Also, my days are only defined by starting with latitude -90.0 and longitude 0.0 so how would I put that into the code? Sorry, I am new to Python.

Comment: @Sjcarlso It means 'use spaces or tabs as separator' since by default csv is comma separated and looking from your posted data it's tab / space delimited. Other files won't be a problem since you are only reading one file. For the day variable, you could set day = 0 before the for loop and increment it if lat == 0 and long == 0

Comment: This is the code I put together but I'm getting the error 'cannot convert float NaN to integer'.<br/> `import numpy as np <br/>

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Saman\\OneDrive\\Documents\\density.txt', delimiter = ' ') <br/>
rho = np.zeros((5, 91, 181)) <br/>
day = 0 <br/>
for i, e in df.iterrows(): <br/>
    lat = int((e['Latitude'] + 90) / 2) <br/>
    long = int(e['Longitude'] / 2) <br/>
    if lat == -90.0 and long == 0.0: <br/>
        day = i <br/>
    rho[day, lat, long] = e['rho'] ` <br/>

Comment: @Sjcarlso The error means there's some missing column in the file so the program fails to convert the float number (latitude or longitude) into an integer index (lat or long). By the way, you should update day to day + 1, not i (the line number); and the condition for update is lat == 0 and long == 0 (integers) since these two variables are already converted from the raw lat/long floats.

Comment: I'm confused because all of the columns are there in the text file. I thought it might be because of the labels 'Latitude', 'Longitude', and 'rho' causing the NaN, but if I remove those the rest of the code won't work. Is there a way to see where the missing column is or how to fix it?

Comment: By missing column I mean a missing number in one row, not the entire column. You can print(e) for each row and check its content before the error happens. The first row is needed because that's the header and it is properly handled in read_csv function.

Comment: Okay that helps. I did print(e) before the error was occurring and got this. Do you think it's the first column in the text file with 0, 1, 2, 3, etc causing the issue?

Comment: Unnamed: 0     0.000000e+00
Unnamed: 1              NaN
Unnamed: 2              NaN
Unnamed: 3              NaN
Unnamed: 4              NaN
Unnamed: 5              NaN
Unnamed: 6              NaN
Latitude                NaN
Unnamed: 8              NaN
Longitude     -9.000000e+01
Unnamed: 10             NaN
Unnamed: 11             NaN
Unnamed: 12             NaN
Unnamed: 13             NaN
Unnamed: 14             NaN
Unnamed: 15             NaN
Unnamed: 16             NaN
Unnamed: 17    0.000000e+00
Unnamed: 18             NaN

Comment: Unnamed: 19    3.396760e-12
rho                     NaN
Name: 0, dtype: float64

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219130/discussion-between-zwang-and-sjcarlso).